# Width of some columns in table

Tags: tables

I want to create a table with the following layout

[image]

So far, I have produced this:

[image]

with the code at the end of this post.
My problem is apparent: I want the columns with X and Y to have the same width (i.e. their individual widths should be half of the width of the 3rd column in the header row), but I don't know how to do this.
What's a simple solution here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{c||c||c|c}
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        Some 
        \\
        text
      \end{tabular}
      &
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        Some more \\ text
      \end{tabular}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
          Even more text
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{3}{*}{ A }
      & item A1
      & X 
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A2
      & X
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A3
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        if $P = NP$: 42
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{2}{*}{ B }
      & item B1
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Bla }
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item B2
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Blu }
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: using `makecell` package for breaking text in the headers instead of more tables --  and the following additional column syntax -- see the answer below -- the answer contains an edit to contain the table size to 42% of the `textwidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,makecell}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}||>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}||>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}}
      \makecell{ Some \\ text}
      &
      \makecell {Some more \\ text}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
          Even more text
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{3}{*}{ A }
      & item A1
      & X 
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A2
      & X
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A3
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        if $P = NP$: 42
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{2}{*}{ B }
      & item B1
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Bla }
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item B2
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Blu }
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to contain the width of the table you could reduce the size of each column

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,makecell}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.07\textwidth}||>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.15\textwidth}||>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}}
      \makecell{ Some \\ text}
      &
      \makecell {Some more \\ text}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
          Even more text
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{3}{*}{ A }
      & item A1
      & X 
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A2
      & X
      & Y
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item A3
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
        if $P = NP$: 42
      }
      \\
      \hhline{=||=||==}
      \multirow{2}{*}{ B }
      & item B1
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Bla }
      \\
      \cline{2-4}
      & item B2
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Blu }
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I didn't know about `makecell`, certainly a lot better than an infinite amount of tabulars haha..

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your code with `c||c||c|c` parameter of `tabular` and you can add the width to the X item manually:

```
\hbox to1.2cm{\hss X\hss} % instead X
```

This can be done only at one occurrence of X, the X's in next rows are centered automatically. Of course, you have to guess the appropriate value (1.2cm here), but guessed values are in the accepted solution too, note: `p{0.07\textwidth}`